# Analysis for Lie groups

Tags: reference-request

So my goal would be to learn some Lie algebras. I was told that I should study firstly Lie groups, I will have better picture and more motivation in mind. For now, I don't want to study it in depth. For Lie groups I need some manifold theory. The thing is that I forgot many things, even already in multivariable analysis, I had on my undergraduate studies- I was never  interested in it and now I would like to see what should I revise before starting. Anyone has some good notes or a shorter book? All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Naive Lie Algebra with John Stillwell?

Comment: Personally, I am using this course notes by W. Ziller https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/math650/LieGroupsReps.pdf
And you can find the course on Youtube

Comment: For a short and efficient introduction it's hard to beat Tapp's Matrix Groups for Undergraduates. You'll tear through it and then you can dive into something deeper. For careful fundmentals, you might look at Warner's text.